# Vuex: Best practice computed object with dynamic keys

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I got a question about a computed object in Vuex.
For example, I need to fetch an X amount of requests and I store the response in an object with ID and response

```
// In the vuex-state

{
   1: {object-response for ID 1},
   2: {object-response for ID 2},
   3: {object-response for ID 3},
   ...
}
```

What I want to achieve is that I create a getter where I can just pass the ID and retrieve the object.

```
getMyData: state => id => state.example[id]
```

But now I get the problem, the state receives a new response and updates the object of responses, but the getter **getMyData** doesn't retrigger.

Is this a good practice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a good practice.  The Vuex docs call it a [method-style getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access) and it does automatically update in that situation.  So something else must be happening

Comment: There's a typo in question not sure if it's related, the getter should be `getMyData: state => id => state.example[id]`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it in the question.
--- 
Regarding method-style-getter, this is for an array, but I'm using an object.

Comment: Are you using `Vue.set` to add the entries to your object?

Comment: No I'm using Vuex.
So I change it with mutation


[types.ADD_REVIEW] (state, {id, ...rest}) {
    state.reviews[id] = rest
  }

Comment: A getter is just a function so object vs array won't make a difference.  Chances are the problem is related to the way data is set ^^^, or used.

Comment: If you're adding new properties to an object (which you are) you need to use `Vue.set` or you won't get reactivity. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects Vuex state uses exactly the same mechanisms for reactivity behind the scenes so the same rules apply. Just using a mutation is not sufficient for it to work.

Comment: OMG. Thanks guys, I fixed this just by updating my mutation.
`const reviews = state.reviews;
// some changes;
state.reviews = Object.assign({}, ...reviews);
`
Now it works fine...

Comment: The `Vue.set` tip is accurate but it's not necessary if reassigning an object, which is why this worked.